# Un Particular Problema de "templates"

Tags: c++, template

Hola Tengo problemas al usar las plantillas, Pasa lo siguiente: tengo un proyecto en dev C++, y tengo 5 archivos , en los cuales hay la clase  ,   `Nodo` y la clase  `People`,con sus respectivos prototipos y de definiciones  `Pesona.cpp` `Persona.h`y  `Nodo.cpp`y `Nodo.h`y el  `main.cpp`. Al momento de declarar un nodo en el main me arroja el siguiente Error  `undefined reference to Nodo<People>::Nodo()`y `` undefined reference to `Nodo<People>::~Nodo() ``.**¿qué tengo mal?**

```
 #include "Nodo.h"

int main() 
{
    People A; 
    cout << A.GetNom() << endl; 
    Nodo<People> B; <--** ASI ESTA BIEN????**
    return 0;
}
```

Archivos de prototipos el .h

```
#ifndef PEOPLE_H
#define PEOPLE_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 
class People
{
    private: 
       string Nom; 
    public:
        People();
       ~People();
        string GetNom(); 
    protected:
};
#endif
```

Archivos de definición .cpp

```
#include "People.h"
People::People()
:Nom("jorge"){;}
People::~People(){cout << "Persona destruido" << endl ; }
string People::GetNom(){return Nom ; }
```

Archivos de prototipos el .h

```
#ifndef NODO_H
#define NODO_H
#include "People.h"
template <class T>
class Nodo
{
    private :
        T Info ; 
    public:
        Nodo();
        Nodo(T); 
       ~Nodo();
        T GetInfo(); 
    protected:
};
#endif
```

Archivos de definición .cpp

```
#include "Nodo.h"
template <class T>
Nodo<T>::Nodo()
:Info(NULL){;}
template <class T>
Nodo<T>::~Nodo(){cout << "Nodo destruido" << endl ; }
template <class T>
Nodo<T>::Nodo(T Obj){Info = Obj ; }
template <class T>
T Nodo<T>::GetInfo(){return Info ;}
```

Comment: Considera dejar la edición que hice pues una pregunta con el mensaje de error en el título es mas objetiva y atrayente que una que dice un problema con.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no instanciaste los objetos. Fijate el tema de [RAII](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII)

Algunas sugerencias:

People.hh

```
#pragma once // esta es la guarda de c++
#include <string>

class People
{
private: 
    std::string Nom; 
public:
    People();
    ~People(); //no hace falta, no usaste el operador new
    std::string GetNom(); 
protected:
};
```

People.cc

```
#include "People.hh"
#include <iostream>

People::People():Nom("jorge"){}

People::~People()
{
    std::cout << "Persona destruido" << std::endl;
}

std::string People::GetNom()
{
    return Nom;
}
```

El tema de tu template. ¿Podrías comentarme un poco sobre que querés lograr? porque tiene errores. Así te puedo tirar una mano.

Según lo conversado, podés encarar el problema como lo plantea el lenguaje JAVA. Con una clase raíz "Obj"

```
class Obj 
{
public:
    virtual std::string get_name();
    virtual std::string identify();
};

class People: public Obj
{
// todo lo que ya teníamos
    std::string get_name()
    {
        return name;
    }
    std::string identify()
    {
        return "I'm a person":
    }
};

class Animal: public Obj
{
// todo lo que tenga un animal
    std::string get_name()
    {
        return name;
    }
    std::string identify()
    {
        return "I'm an animal";
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Obj **objects = new Obj[2] { 0 };
    objects[0] = new People();
    objects[1] = new Animal();
    std::cout << objects[0]->identify() << " " << objects[0]->get_name() << std:endl;
    std::cout << objects[1]->identify() << " " << objects[1]->get_name() << std::endl;
    delete objects[0];
    delete objects[1];
    delete objects;
}
```

Comment: Gonzalo te agradezco mucho tu tiempo para revisar mi código, de vedad muchas gracias.

Comment: Gonzalo, Tengo una lista la cual administra nodos los cuales tienen objetos , lo que yo quiero hacer es que el nodo me sirva para distintos objetos , ya que dependiendo el tipo de objeto tengo que adaptar el nodo, es por eso que estoy utilizando plantillas. lo que quiero es un nodo universal, por así decirlo , Muchas gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: Vale, necesitas un contenedor. ¿Hay alguna razón por la cual std::vector no te sirva?. Más que nada por que la idea del template es evitar la sobrecarga de funciones. ¿Los nodos tienen alguna funcionalidad en particular que no te ofrezca std::vector? ¿o estás tratando de lograr poliformismo?

Comment: Hola de Nuevo Gonzalo , En este problema no puedo utilizar contendores ni std::vector , ya que las reglas para solucionar este , me prohíben utilizar contenedores. Agradezco tu valiosa ayuda. voy a tratar de implementar  el Polimorfismo, cualquier otra ayuda estaré muy agradecido.